# Nested Table Joins

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have C table as Main Table, which is joining left join with E table on col3 and which is joining left join with F table on col4.

```
(
    FROM A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.col1 = B.col1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN C ON A.col2 = C.col2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN E ON A.col3 = E.col3
    LEFT OUTER JOIN F ON A.col4 = F.col4

)temptab1
```

Which needs to left join with

```
(
   FROM C ON
    LEFT OUTER JOIN E ON C.col3 = E.col3
    LEFT OUTER JOIN F ON C.col4 = F.col4

)temptab2
```

Now, should i join temptab1 to temptab2 on `(C.Col3 = temptab2.Col3 OR C.Col4 = temptab2.Col4)` ? OR
should i join temptab1 to temptab2 on `(C.Col3 = temptab2.Col3 AND C.Col4 = temptab2.Col4)` ?

IF i have to use OR clause, it is hindering performance of the query a lot...

I tried using union clause instead of OR clause. Still, query performance is not improving...

Please suggest better query.

Comment: do you have proper indexing in tables and have you check the query plan?

Comment: @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin  Yes i am using Indexes on joined columns. Still query is running more than 2 hours....Client wants this query to run within 10-15 minutes...

Comment: @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin I am using Index hints based on joined columns..Still, Query execution time is not improving...

Comment: Why `A.col3` present in `temptab2`? There is no such table whose alias is A in `temptab2`

Comment: Corrected @Tejash Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Once you joined the sub-queries, there would be no tables C or D or E available for you to mention them. You can only join them by using column mentioned in SELECT clause of both the sub-queries. So Please post your sub-select clause also to get the correct join predicates.

Comment: Why don't you replace the join with `C` in `temptab1` with `temptab2`?

Comment: @Radagast81  there is a inter-dependency of derived fields from TempTable2 to TempTable1.

Comment: You don't say how output is a function of input, so why do you expect us to know what query will calculate that? Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL. PS Clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

The temptab1 is all rows of A. The temptab2 is all rows of C. And the temptab1 is LEFT JOIN with temptab2, which results in all rows of A.
You may use CASE statements to identify the matching values across A, B, C, D, E, F and remove the Join with temptab2.
Apologies, could not comment...

Comment: " the temptab1 is LEFT JOIN with temptab2, which results in all rows of A" => temptable2 left join temptable1 on conditions, whose the result set in all rows of C but not A...

Comment: In that case, where you need all records from C, its best to make C as the driving table instead of A.

Comment: the relationships are defined like that sir.

Comment: 1st query returns not just all rows of A, you may have duplicates aswell if other tables have duplicates values on the joined columns